# New sheets from list, copy template into newsheets, and name cell A1 after sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, templates

I just learned about VBA yesterday and am pretty excited to keep learning. That said, I have a report that i run for work out of SharePoint and make a new sheet for each line of the report (Sheet named "Matrix"). Each sheet gets named based on the first cell in each row. I then have a template (sheet named "Hidden") that i copy into each sheet that was created. Lastly, I have to name cell A1 after the name of the sheet. From there, formulas in the template kick in and fill in the rest of the template based on information from the Matrix.

So far, I am able to scrub the data in Matrix, and create the new sheets with names properly (thanks to all the answers to questions I've found on this site so far!). I can't find any information on how to copy a template into multiple new sheets and name a cell within each sheet after the sheet name. I don't imagine this would be difficult.

Here is what i have so far (I'm sorry it's not exactly elegant - as I said, I just started coding yesterday).

```
    Sub FullMacro()
    ' Replace Macro
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
     [C:C].Select
    With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
    End With

    ' Dropdown SheetName
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matrix")
    LastRow = Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(Worksheets("Matrix").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Select

    ' SortNumber Macro
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
     ("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With

    ' Add Named Sheets
    LastRow = Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(Worksheets("Matrix").Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Matrix").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    ' MoveMatrix Macro
    Sheets("Matrix").Select
    Sheets("Matrix").Move Before:=Sheets(1)

    ' ReSortNumber Macro
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("C1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Matrix").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If Worksheet.Name = "SheetName" Then
    Worksheet.Delete 
    End If
    Next Worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of adding new sheets and copying the template in, it's simpler to just [`copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) the template worksheet and then rename.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! How might I do that for a variable number of sheets? For instance, if the Matrix has 12 rows (not counting the header), how do I make 12 copies of the template, then rename each new sheet and first cell in each sheet after the first row in the matrix? I'm sure that in VBA, there's a simple enough way of doing it, but it seems like that is more steps. (Then again, I'm not a coder by any means, so what do I know?) :)

Comment: You already have a loop that handles the variable number of sheets: `For i = 1 to LastRow`. So within that loop, instead of using `Sheets.Add`, copy the template and rename.

Comment: ahh, i get it.  thank you! Then once that's done, what code might i use to select a1 in each new sheet and fill in with the name of the sheet? I'm sure that it might be easiest to just select all sheets that are not "Matrix" or "Hidden", yes? Still... what would that code look like?

Comment: No need to select all the sheets. Modify `Range("A1").Value` of each new sheet within the loop.

Comment: oh, good call! You can probably see from the code i posted that i tend to think in steps, rather than thinking about combining efforts into one step(again, not a coder). Thanks for your help! I think this should work.